# problems installing a virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtualization

I am tryin to install kali linux 1.0.9 on virtualbox for some testing purposes. (I am new with virtual machines). So i downloaded the 64-bit version of the os. i have got two problems:-

1. for some reason virtualbox does not show me a debian 64 bit version option in the settings(however it does show 32-bit option).
2. virtualbox doesnt allow me to change the no. of processors(default value is 1). i have got 8 cpus.

please help. my specs - intel i7 2670 memory- 6GB HDD-700 GB graphics - radeon 7670 HD
I have got windows 7 ultimate 64-Bit installed on the host

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable 'Virtualization' option in your BIOS settings. The name of the settings may be different in different BIOS/motherboard brands. But you can easily identify it, in the BIOS.

Comment: This answer has it right about BIOS settings.  If you have difficulty getting to your BIOS settings, try the F1, F2, and Delete keys (not at the same time) when your PC is in the first few seconds of booting.  There may be an indication on your startup screen (often it will show the manufacturer of the PC) as to which key is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. I am in windows 8.1 and for my case, the problem was due to conflicts with Hyper-V who was activated in my system. I solved the problem by disabling Hyper-V. 
Open windows features and  Uncheck Hyper-V, click/tap on OK